# QWebEngineView does not load relative resources from an html page if the page is loaded from Qt RCC resource system

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-resource, qwebengineview

**edit**: Following @eyllanesc comment, here is [a minimal example hosted on github](https://github.com/Adnn/so_QrcRelativePath). The test is run on Qt5.9, on OS X 10.12.

### Base HTML

Let's create a minimal example HTML loading an image by relative path, *test.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>Image:</div>
      <img src="img.jpg"></img>
  </body>
</html>
```

This file is created in a folder also containing *img.jpg* (which should be a picture of an adorable puppy)

When *test.html* is opened directly in the browser, it shows the image as expected.

### The problem with qrc and relative paths

Now, if we embed both resources into a Qt application, with the following .qrc file:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">

<qresource>
    <file alias="test.html">resources/web/test.html</file>
    <file alias="img.jpg">resources/web/img.jpg</file>
</qresource>

</RCC>
```

We can open the HTML page in a `QWebEngineView` with some code of the form:

```
mWebView->load(QUrl{"qrc:///test.html"});
```

The page is loaded, but the image is not.

Enabling the web developer console (by running the app with argument `--remote-debugging-port=8888`) and going to the Network tab, we can see that there is **not even an attempt** to load *img.jpg*.

#### With absolute path, no problem

If the image element was changed to `<img src="qrc:///img.jpg"></img>`, then everything works fine and the image is loaded.

### Questions

- Is this limitation of the qrc system by design?
- Is there a way to work around it? (without hardcoding the absolute path with the scheme)

Comment: I have tried your code and I have not had any problems, maybe I made a mistake in reproducing your error. Maybe you could provide a complete test through github or similar.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for your comment, there is now a minimal example showing the error: https://github.com/Adnn/so_QrcRelativePath

Comment: I already post my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be how the URL of the .html file is declared:

In the case of @ad-n he followed the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#resource-collection-files-op-op-qrc):

> ...
>
> For example, the file path :/images/cut.png or the URL
> **qrc:///** images/cut.png would give access to the cut.png file, whose
> location in the application's source tree is images/cut.png. This can
> be changed using the file tag's alias attribute:
>
> ...

And use: `qrc:///home.html`

However in my case I used Qt Creator to provide me the url as shown in the following image:

[image]

And use: `qrc:/home.html`

That's why I work on my case.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating the problem, it turns out that getting rid of all aliases in the *.rcc* file, and changing the resource path accordingly in the code, make it possible to use relative pathes.

Here are the changes to the sources:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">

<qresource>
    <file>resources/web/test.html</file>
    <file>resources/web/img.jpg</file>
</qresource>

</RCC>
```

-

```
mWebView->load(QUrl{"qrc:///resources/web/test.html"});
```

I do not accept this answer yet, as it feels like a workaround. Hopefully there is a way to have it work with aliases.

Comment: I have tried it with and without alias and I have not had problems.

Comment: @eyllanesc Interesting! Are you using Qt5.9? Did you try the github example now provided with the question?

Comment: I am using qt 5.9.1 on Linux, but with your code I have problems, I am trying to find the problem.

Comment: Please try with this code: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/so_QrcRelativePath-master

Comment: @eyllanesc It seems you replaced `qrc:///test.html` with `qrc:/test.html`, and it **does** work with the aliases! Nice catch, yet it is very surprising to me that it is working, as [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#resource-collection-files-op-op-qrc) uses `qrc:///`. If you turn it into an answer, it will be accepted ; )

Comment: When I want to copy a URL or path use Qt Creator, it generates this data as shown in the [image](http://imgur.com/a/UjGMO)

Comment: OKay, I'll post that response.